# Error when trying to start Azure Container Instance using Invoke-AzResourceAction: No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI

Tags: azure, azure-container-instances

I am trying to start an Azure Container Instance using a PowerShell task in a YAML pipeline:

```
    - task: AzurePowerShell@5
    displayName: Start container instances
    inputs:
        azureSubscription: ${{ parameters.Subscription }}
        ScriptType: "InlineScript"
        azurePowerShellVersion: OtherVersion
        preferredAzurePowerShellVersion: "4.4.0"
        Inline: |

        $cg = Get-AzContainerGroup -ResourceGroupName "MyResourceGroup" -Name "updateproxy"
        Invoke-AzResourceAction -ResourceId $cg.Id -Action start -Force
```

But this fails with the following error (NOTE: I replaced the subscription id with [guid]):

```
No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'https://provider-westeurope.console.azure.com/providers/api/subscriptions/[guid]/resourceGroups/MyResourceGroup/providers/Microsoft.ContainerInstance/containerGroups/updateproxy/start?api-version=2021-03-01'.
```

When I retry the pipeline it succeeds without any error.

After stopping the container instance and running the pipeline again, it fails again with the same error.

What can I do to prevent this error from happening?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the same problem as you. I fixed the problem by specifying the `ApiVersion` to be `"2019-12-01"` in the call to `Invoke-AzureRmResourceAction`.

```
Invoke-AzureRmResourceAction -ResourceId $cg.Id -Action start -Force -ApiVersion "2019-12-01"
```

The API specifies it actually:

```
POST https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.ContainerInstance/containerGroups/{containerGroupName}/start?api-version=2019-12-01
```

**Source:** https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/container-instances/containergroups/start